# Отсутствует виртуальный микрофон

Tags: c#, winforms, naudio

Должен появляться виртуальный микрофон, но увы нету.
Что делать?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NAudio.Wave;
using NAudio.CoreAudioApi;

namespace CustomMic
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private WasapiLoopbackCapture virtualMicrophone;
        private AudioFileReader audioFile;
        private WaveOut waveOut;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            virtualMicrophone = new WasapiLoopbackCapture(); // Создаем виртуальный микрофон
            audioFile = new AudioFileReader("C:\\Users\\Negr\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\Test1\\Test.mp3"); // Укажите путь к вашему MP3 файлу
            waveOut = new WaveOut();

            virtualMicrophone.DataAvailable += VirtualMicrophoneOnDataAvailable;
        }

        private void VirtualMicrophoneOnDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
        {
            if (waveOut == null) // Проверяем, был ли объект waveOut инициализирован
            {
                waveOut = new WaveOut(); // Если не был, то инициализируем
                waveOut.Init(audioFile); // Инициализируем waveOut с аудио файлом
            }
            else
            {
                if (waveOut.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Stopped) // Если состояние воспроизведения было остановлено
                {
                    waveOut.Play(); // Начинаем воспроизведение
                }
            }

            byte[] buffer = new byte[e.BytesRecorded];
            audioFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Обработчик события для кнопки "Start"
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
            {
                virtualMicrophone.StartRecording(); // Запускаем запись виртуального микрофона
            });
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Обработчик события для кнопки "Stop"
        {
            virtualMicrophone.StopRecording(); // Останавливаем запись виртуального микрофона
            audioFile.Position = 0; // Сбрасываем позицию воспроизведения аудио файла
            waveOut.Stop(); // Останавливаем воспроизведение
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что он должен появиться?

Comment: chatgpt написал такой код)

Comment: мне надо было создать вирт микро